# Obtain inner functions names

Tags: python-3.x

Retrieving inner function names

I have tried to use dis.Bytecode and checking for call_function and other instruction values but couldn't obtain the inner function names.

```
def hello():
  a = [1,2]
  b = ["apple", "banana"]
  for i,v in enumerate(a):
    print(i,v)
  print(tuple(zip(a,b)))
```

I would like to know how I can retrieve the names of the inner functions used - enumerate(), print(), tuple() and zip()

Answer (score 0):

`dis.code_info(hello)` solves it!